# How to open an installed plugin such as realCentroid using Custom built plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have built my custom plugin by name ABTD plugin
I have installed the plugin named real centroid in qgis.
Now,
I want to add a button to my plugin which will in turn open the "real centroid" plugin dialog box which has been installed by me in QGIS.

Is it possible?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to review the plugin's script, find how to call it. For `realCentroid`, use the following lines for the click event of the button in your script:

```
def button_clicked(self):
    from realcentroid.realcentroid import RealCentroid
    rc = RealCentroid(self.iface)
    rc.run()
```

If you want to test it in QGIS Python Console, try this:

```
from realcentroid.realcentroid import RealCentroid
rc = RealCentroid(iface)
rc.run()
```

**How to build the import part:**

In `from realcentroid.realcentroid import RealCentroid`

- The first `realcentroid` is the folder name of the plugin.

  [image]
- The second `realcentroid` is the main module that `__init.py__` uses.

  [image]
- `RealCentroid` is the main class in the main module.

  [image]

`run` method is not mandatory. We call it because `run`  method in `RealCentroid` class contains the line that opens the plugin dialog window. Therefore, you must review the main class to find how to open that dialog window. It depends.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But i had one doubt - how to find its calling name?

Comment: I've added more explanation.