# Calling "Remove empty layers" plugin from the Python Console in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-python-console

I've stumbled upon a great plug-in called "[Remove empty layers](https://github.com/gacarrillor/RemoveEmptyLayers)", developed by @Germán Carrillo.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use this plug-in in the Python Console.

Comment: Does this tool remove the empty Layers just from the project or also from disk?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. It is possible using the following lines.

```
from RemoveEmptyLayers.removeemptylayers import RemoveEmptyLayers
remove = RemoveEmptyLayers(iface)
remove.run()
```

Please also check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/443043/29431) to understand what all `removeemptylayers` phrases mean.